# PHPStorm not disconnecting with XDEBUG on MacOS X

Tags: php, macos, nginx, xdebug, remote-debugging

I am having connection difficulties with PHPStorm 8.x and remote XDEBUG running on a nginx server, wherein XDEBUG doesn't terminate upon cancelling the HTTP Request during a site reload or navigating to a different url.

The issue occurs sporadic, sometimes quickly turning the Debug-Listening button on and off helps terminating and breaking anew at a preset breakpoint.
PHPStorm has been continuously upgraded to the latest version since 8.0. PHP/XDebug are used in the following versions, on an nginx server:

```
PHP 5.4.36-1~dotdeb.0 (cli) (built: Dec 19 2014 22:51:27) 
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.6, Copyright (c) 2002-2014, by Derick Rethans
```

The PHP> Debug Settings in PHPStorm are set as follows:

[image: PHPStorm Debug Settings]

Any help or pointers are highly appreciated.